# How to run Django project locally for Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django project and the structure is as following,

[image]

[image]

Inside the `Procfile`, I have this code,

```
web: gunicorn team-app.wsgi --log-file -
```

This is the `requirements.txt`,

```
appdirs==1.4.3
coreapi==2.3.0
coreschema==0.0.4
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.11
django-allauth==0.31.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.1
django-rest-swagger==2.1.2
djangorestframework==3.6.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
itypes==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
oauthlib==2.0.2
openapi-codec==1.3.1
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-openid==2.2.5
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.13.0
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
simplejson==3.10.0
six==1.10.0
uritemplate==3.0.0
whitenoise==3.3.0
```

`env` is the `virtualenv` installed locally. When I enter in the `root` folder, `team-app` and run the command `heroku local web`, I get the following error,

[image]

[image]

So, the issue is `ImportError: No module named team-app.wsgi` and I believe the location of the `Procfile` or something is not correct. The `wsgi.py` file in the `users_groups` is as following,

```
"""
WSGI config for users_groups project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "users_groups.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I can provide additional informations if required. How to solve this issue?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your screenshot, but it looks like your `requirements.txt` and `Procfile` are in a subdirectory? They [should be in](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#the-basics) the [root project directory](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile). It also looks like your entire Django application is inside a subdirectory called `src/`; it might also have to be moved up a level. Normally I would use that as my project root. Does your Git repository live at the `src/` level, or the `team-app/` level?

Comment: `1.` Both the `requirements.txt and Procfile` are inside the top level of the `team-app` .
`2.` This is correct, the entire Django app is inside the `src` folder. I don't believe this is an issue or it is ?
`3.` `Git` lives in the `team-app/` level.

I put a new picture for the `project structure` with the question to understand it easily.

Comment: When I first started using Django on Heroku I remember having to use my main Django directory as my project root. That was a few years ago, so maybe it no longer applies, but it's worth a try. Try moving `Procfile` into `src/`, then `cd` into `src/` and try running `heroku local web` from there (with `Procfile` referring to `users_groups.wsgi`).

Comment: This is actually worked. Would you like to write it as an answer? I believe it will be helpful.

Comment: Great! I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. **The first is Django-related:**

> ImportError: No module named team-app.wsgi

Your `wsgi.py` file is located in the `users_groups/` directory so your `Procfile` should reference `users_groups.wsgi`:

```
web: gunicorn users_groups.wsgi --log-file -
```

The name of the top-level directory that contains the entire project is irrelevant.

**The second problem is Heroku-related.** Heroku expects the Django directory to be the root of your repository. Moving `Procfile` into `src/`, then running `heroku local web` should get you up and running locally.

When you deploy to Heroku you'll have to make sure your current `src/` directory is your root directory. That may mean moving some files into `src/` and recreating / refactoring your Git repository there, or it could mean moving everything that's currently in `src/` up a level.

Comment: It doesn't  work, I get the error `ImportError: No module named users_groups.wsgi`. I thought it should be `project_name.wsgi`.

Comment: I also tried version like `src.users_groups.wsgi` and `src.main.users_groups.wsgi`. I guess the issue is around it but not solved so far.